# Can I create @metadata tags in Logstash?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I know Logstash 1.5 supports a hidden field `[@metadata]`, is it possible to create a `[@metadata][foo]` tag that will behave similarly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [@metadata][foo] would give you a unique field that you can reference throughout your config and won't be sent to elasticsearch.